# jQuery toggle multiple classes on click

Tags: jquery, toggle, toggleclass

Why I'm not able to toggle multiple classes using onClick event like:

```
<a data-class="tiny"> Tiny</a> 
<a data-class="small"> Small</a> 
<a data-class="big"> Big</a> 
<a data-class="large"> Large</a>


<i class="icon twitter"></i>


  $(document).on('click', 'a[data-class]', function() {
      var aclass = $(this).data('class');
      $(.box).toggleClass(aclass);
  });
```

On each click I end up with all classes assigned to .icon twitter element, wht I would like to happen is append one of the clicked classes and remove others, but keep the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this adding extra classes and id:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".linkClass").click(function(){
  var temp = $(this).id; // contains either tiny, small, big or large

  $(".icon").removeClass("tiny small big large"); // clear any classes added before
  $(".icon").addClass(temp); // adds the required class based on the id of the clicked element.
  });

});
```

```html
<a class="linkClass" id="tiny"> Tiny</a> 
<a class="linkClass" id="small"> Small</a> 
<a class="linkClass" id="big"> Big</a> 
<a class="linkClass" id="large"> Large</a>


<i class="icon twitter"></i>
```